# absolute error and relative error with at least 3 digits chopping for $\frac{{1}}{A}$ $A=\frac{{e}}{2.71828}-2.71828* e^{{-1}}$

Tags: numerical-methods

absolute error and relative error with at least 3 digits chopping for $\frac{{1}}{A}$ $A=\frac{{e}}{2.71828}-2.71828* e^{{-1}}$

My solution:

\begin{align} A=\frac{{e}}{2.71828}-2.71828* e^{{-1}} &= 1.34530544*10^{{-6}} \end{align}
So
\begin{align} \frac{{1}}{A}=\frac{{1}}{\frac{{e}}{2.71828}-2.71828* e^{{-1}}} &= 743325.622 \end{align}
Now for 3 digits chopping :
\begin{align} fl_c(\frac{{fl_c(e)}}{fl_c(2.71828)})=1=0.100*10 \end{align}
\begin{align} fl_c(fl_c(2.71828)*fl_c(e^{{-1}}))=0.994 \end{align}
\begin{align} fl_c(\frac{{fl_c(e)}}{fl_c(2.71828)}-fl_c(2.71828)*fl_c(e^{{-1}})=0.600*10^{{-2}}\end{align}
\begin{align} fl_c(\frac{{1}}{A})=fl_c(\frac{{1}}{{0.600*10^{{-2}}}}) &= 166 \end{align}
\begin{align} AE=|\frac{{1}}{A}-approximation\frac{{1}}{A}|=743159.622\end{align}
My question is why there is so much difference between approximation and actual value? or I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What is $fl_c?{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews $fl_c$ floating point numbers with chopping

Comment: You lose significant digits whenever you subtract two numbers that are relatively close. For instance, if $x=1.23456$ to six significant figures, and $y=1.23457$ to six significant figures, then $x-y$ evaluates to $0.00001$ in six-digit arighmetic, so you are down to (at best) one significant figure of relative accuracy. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054675/428857) for an example of when the relative accuracy is even worse.

Comment: “chopping” is also not a usual English math term, at least not one that I’ve encountered. Does it mean digit truncation?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  Numerical Analysis, Richard L. Burden & J. Douglas
Faires ,the word has been used in the book'Chopping and Rounding'

Comment: You still haven’t defined the term. If you can’t define it, how can you use it?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews oh sorry I know what is it , you are right , it means that digit truncation

Comment: Sorry tent, I can't make sense of that at all

Comment: @TonyK I mean that when I use three-digit rounding arithmetic to evaluate, Approximation is zero. So absolute error and relative error undefined for $\frac{{1}}{A}$